# Where in the world is "Conditional Compilation Symbol?"

Tags: visual-studio-2022, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

If you've transition to VS2022 from the older version of VS, you'll notice the "Conditional Compilation symbols" is gone!

See my solution below on how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Under the project properties
2. Go to Compile/Advanced
3. click on the little wheel under Custom constants (you have to hover over the label)...*yes, I know*
   At this point, things pretty pretty obvious

[image]